# Python Requests-futures slow

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm currently using requests-futures for faster web scraping. The problem is, it's still very slow. Around 1 every other second. Here's how the ThreadPoolExecutor looks:

```
        with FuturesSession(executor=ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)) as session:
            futures = {session.get(url, proxies={
                'http': str(random.choice(proxy_list).replace("https:/", "http:/")),
                'https': str(random.choice(proxy_list).replace("https:/", "http:/")),
            }, headers={
                'User-Agent': str(ua.chrome),
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
            }): url for url in url_list}
            # ---
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                del futures[future]
                try:
                    resp = future.result()
                except:
                    print("Error getting result from thread. Ignoring")
                try:
                    multiprocessing.Process(target=main_func, args=(resp,))
                    del resp
                    del future
                except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
                    logging.warning(
                        "[requests.custom.debug]: requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Error] print(resp.json())")
```

I believe it's slow because of the as_completed for loop since that's not a concurrent loop. As for the main_func I pass the response to, that's the function that uses the information from the site using bs4. If the as_completed for loop would have been concurrent, then it would still be faster than this. I really want the scraper to be faster and I feel like I'd like to keep using requests-futures, but if there's something that's **a lot** faster, I'd be happy to change. So if anyone knows something that's quite a lot faster than requests-futures, then please feel free to share that
Is anyone able to help with this? Thank you

Comment: I've never used FuturesSession only because I prefer to handle the thread management myself. However, I suggest that you add some timing debug prints either side of each GET. My guess is that it's going to be a proxy issue. Is it possible to use a selection of URLs that don't require a proxy?

Comment: Further thought. Why are you using Process? If it's because the response processing is CPU intensive then why not just run sub-processes to do both the HTTP request **and** the processing. Then you won't have to wait for anything

Comment: If you are talking about using Process when I pass the response to the main_func: I'm using Process because when using Thread at that part, I would get a memory leak. When using Process, both the CPU and Memory will stay stable, but with Thread the memory will continue to rise and not stop. I believe it's slow because of the as_completed for loop since that won't be going at the same time.

Comment: You will not get a memory leak. Do everything in a Process

Comment: I'm don't quite understand. What do you mean with everything in a Process? Do you mean using ProcessPoolExecutor instead of ThreadPoolExecutor? If so, I've already tried that and not much changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a restructure of the code which should help:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import random

proxy_list = [
    'http://107.151.182.247:80',
    'http://194.5.193.183:80',
    'http://88.198.50.103:8080',
    'http://88.198.24.108:8080',
    'http://64.44.164.254:80',
    'http://47.74.152.29:8888',
    'http://176.9.75.42:8080']

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1500.55 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'}

url_list = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://facebook.com', 'http://twitter.com']

def process(url):
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    https = proxy.replace('http:', 'https:')
    http = proxy.replace('https:', 'http:')
    proxies = {'http': http, 'https': https}
    try:
        (r := requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)).raise_for_status()
        # call main_func here
    except Exception as e:
        return e
    return 'OK'



def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for result in executor.map(process, url_list):
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The proxy_list may not work for you. Use your own proxy list.

Obviously the url_list will not match yours.

The point of this is that each URL is handled in its own process. There really is no need to mix threads and processes in this scenario especially as it adds a degree of synchronicity while you wait for threads to complete before running a sub-process.